# Is it possible to call appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget() in worker thread?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-anr-dialog

Hello? I'm making an android app widget.

There are many data related ui from DB in my widget.

So to avoid Broadcast Receiver ANR Issue, I made a remoteView and loaded data from db and set the data related ui in the remoteView.

Finally I called `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews)`, and app widget were updated correctly.

But, I remember that UI update related logic must be in UI thread.

So, I wonder that can I still call appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget() in worker thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I remember that UI update related logic must be in UI thread.

Correct, but your code has nothing to do with an UI in your app.

> I wonder that can I still call appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget() in worker thread?

A `RemoteViews` is a data structure that describes a UI that *another process* will render. You are welcome to create such a data structure and hand it to the OS on a background thread. That other process will wind up using its main application thread for rendering the UI that is described by your `RemoteViews`.